# Mysql connection pool performance loss

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, connection-pooling, hikaricp

I've a Java application that can run either in Jboss and Glassfish.

I've used Hibernate to handle the DB and hikariCP as connection pool.

All works perfectly but I've noticed a performance loss.

To make a stress test I've created a test servlet that select from DB a row using hibernate.

With JMeter I've set 500 simultaneusly request per sec to this servlet, while JMeter is running i've tryed to use the application and the behavior is the following:

When I set maximumPoolSize to 10 the application responds after very long time (~10 sec).
When I set the maximumPoolSize to 1 the application responds as expected (after 2 or 3 sec)

Another thing I've noticed is that when I run JMeter with 500 threads and 10 maximum connection pool, the apllication JMeter become freeze while with 1 maximum connection pool the application JMeter never become freeze.

What is the reason of this behavior? I've missed some configuration on mysql?

### Hibernate config

```
    <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSourceClassName">com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout">15000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.maxLifetime">900000</property><!-- 15 min -->
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.leakDetectionThreshold">5000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.validationTimeout">1000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.minimumIdle">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.cachePrepStmts">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.prepStmtCacheSize">250</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit">2048</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDb?transformedBitIsBoolean=false&tinyInt1isBit=false&UseUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8</property>
```

Comment: Did you change other properties from hikaricp? Can you show the file with your hicaricp configurations?

Comment: @Dherik Thanks for response, I've added the hibernate config